# name 'displayhtml' is not defined in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have upgraded my code from Django 1.8 to Django 3.0

and my python version is python 3.7

when i deploy my code to dev server i m getting this issue "name 'displayhtml' is not defined"

my requirements.txt

```
django-recaptcha== 2.0.6
```

settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
 ....
....
'captcha',

]
```

here is my views.py

```
from recaptcha.client.captcha import *
    def enquiry_external(request, client_pk):
        form_data={}
        admin = ClientUser.objects.filter(client_id=client_pk,is_admin=True)[0].id
        user_id = request.user
        public_key = settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY
        script = displayhtml(public_key=public_key)
        id = request.GET.get('gid','')
        .....
        .....
        .....
```

I couldn't understand why i m getting this error

```
from crm.views import *
[project@ec2-36-248-123-17.eu-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com] out:   File "/home/project/deploy/mcam080222-1/server/mcam/crm/views.py", line 112, in <module>
[project@ec2-36-248-123-17.eu-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com] out:     from recaptcha.client.captcha import *
[project@ec2-36-248-123-17.eu-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com] out: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'recaptcha
```

'

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: did you import `displayhtml` from captcha ?

Comment: i have edited my question